# How to prove $\Phi(T)$ is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was trying to prove the theorem about $\Phi$ on my textbook (Linear Algebra $4^\text{th}$ edition : Theorem $2.20$ p.$103$).

The theorem:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over $F$ of dimensions $n$ and $m$, respectively, and let $\beta, \gamma$ be ordered bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively. Then the function $\Phi:L(V,W) \to M_{m \times n}(F)$,defined by $\Phi(T)=[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}$ for $T \in L(V,W)$, is an isomorphism.

There is a proof on my book but I'm having trouble understanding it.

So it first mentioned that $\Phi$ is linear, which can be proved (Not sure how to prove it).

Then it says that we need to show $\Phi$ is one-to-one and onto (why both? if we can prove $\Phi$ is linear then one-to-one is equivalent to onto, right?)

Finally it says, it is accomplished if we can show: for every $m \times n$ matrix $A$ there is a unique linear transformation $T:V \to W$. Then conclude that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism?

Could anyone help with above questions? Many Thanks!

Comment: I think $\gamma$ should be $\alpha$ on the theorem statement.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right, I'll edit my question

Comment: You prove $\Phi$ is linear the obvious way: show that if $T$ and $U$ are linear transformations and $\alpha$ is a scalar, then the matrix for $\alpha T+U$ is the matrix $\alpha[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma} + [U]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$.

Comment: Yes, one-to-one is equivalent to onto in the finite dimensional case; that’s why they tell you to show it is onto and then conclude it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the book you're using is Friedberg, Insel, and Spence.

First, $\Phi$ is linear by Theorem 2.8 on page 82: $$\Phi(a\mathsf{T} + \mathsf{U}) = [a\mathsf{T}+\mathsf{U}]_\beta^\gamma = [a\mathsf{T}]_\beta^\gamma + [\mathsf{U}]_\beta^\gamma = a[\mathsf{T}]_\beta^\gamma + [\mathsf{U}]_\beta^\gamma = a\Phi(\mathsf{T}) + \Phi(\mathsf{U}).$$ 
Theorem 2.8 is what allows you to write the second and third equals signs above. The rest of the equals signs come from the definition of $\Phi$.

Your next two questions are addressed by reading the two sentences *together*.  Here's the full quote:

> Hence we must show that $\Phi$ is one-to-one and onto. This is accomplished if we show that for every $m \times n$ matrix $A$, there exists a unique linear transformation $\mathsf{T}:\mathsf{V} \to \mathsf{W}$ such that $\Phi(\mathsf{T}) = A$.

When you have a linear map between spaces of the same finite dimension, to show it's an isomorphism, it's enough to prove *one of* "one-to-one" or "onto".  However, at this point in the book, you do not yet know that $\mathcal{L}(\mathsf{V}, \mathsf{W})$ is finite-dimensional when $\mathsf{V}$ and $\mathsf{W}$ are.  The goal of Theorem 2.20 is to show that $\mathcal{L}(\mathsf{V}, \mathsf{W})$ is isomorphic to $\mathsf{M}_{m\times n}(F)$ by constructing the isomorphism $\Phi$. Thus we have to show *both* "one-to-one" *and* "onto": this is accomplished just as the quote says.

Comment: One-to-one and onto are only equivalent between spaces of the *same* (finite) dimension. Finite dimensionality is not enough on its own; you need to know the dimension $L(V, W)$. Further, the proof is trying to establish more than just onto. The word "unique" also implies one-to-one.

Comment: Yes I'm using Friedberg, Insel, and Spence! The part about linearly proof I'm not getting is that, 2.8 says we need to have linear transformations T and U first, then the equations should hold. Please correct me if I'm not understanding it right. but how can we use 2.8 to prove that a transformation is linear? Thanks

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for noticing that! I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DesiredOB Theorem 2.8 is not used for arbitrary transformations; it's used to say that $[a\mathsf{T}] = a[\mathsf{T}]$ and $[\mathsf{T} + \mathsf{U}] = [\mathsf{T}] + [\mathsf{U}]$ -- that expressing a transformation as a matrix is itself a linear operation.

Comment: Ah.. I'm getting how the linearly is proved now. Thanks a lot! And now I got how one-to-one and onto is proved, but how can we conclude that Φ is an isomorphism by knowing Φ is linear and both one-to-one and onto?

Comment: @DesiredOB By the **Definitions** on the bottom of page 102, an isomorphism is an invertible linear transformation. Invertible means one-to-one and onto (see the note on the top of page 100; Theorem 2.5 is on page 71).

Comment: Missed p.100's note.. Got it now. Thanks!

Comment: @DesiredOB You're welcome. If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted!